# Protobuf-net / NetCore2: Deserialization ignores annotated private fields

Tags: serialization, .net-core, protobuf-net, .net-standard, private-members

**Edit: The problem was with [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy). Protobuf-net (de)serializes marked private fields just fine.**

I am running a NetCore 2.0 unit test project. Protobuf-net appears to be ignored private fields even though the have the `[ProtoMember]` attribute.

```
[ProtoContract]
internal class Model
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Example { get; private set; } // Works

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private List<int> _a; // Not deserialized unless made public

    public IEnumerable<int> A => this._a;

    public Model(int example, IEnumerable<int> a)
    {
        this.Example = example;
        this._a = a.ToList(); // Copy prevents mutation
    }

    private Model() // For deserialization
    {
    }
}
```

I have used a public `IEnumerable<int>` to avoid mutability and hide implementation details. It is backed by a private `List<int>` to allow serialization. However, **protobuf-net will only *de*serialize the field if I make it public**. The serialization, on the other hand, will actually include the data even if the field is private.

Is this intended behavior? Is there are a clean way to make protobuf-net honor the marked private field when deserializing?

P.S. The same behavior is seen for non-collection members, but I have demonstrated with `IEnumerable`/`List` because it shows the reason for this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works identically (apart from the first line of the output) when targetting `netcoreapp2.0` or `net45`. I'd be happy to help, but I'd need to see an example that fails. I'm using:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="2.3.6" />
```

Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ProtoBuf;
[ProtoContract]
internal class Model
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Example { get; private set; } // Works

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private List<int> _a; // Not deserialized unless made public

    public IEnumerable<int> A => this._a;

    public Model(int example, IEnumerable<int> a)
    {
        this.Example = example;
        this._a = a.ToList(); // Copy prevents mutation
    }

    private Model() // For deserialization
    {
    }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
#if NETCOREAPP2_0
        Console.WriteLine(".NET Core 2.0");
#elif NET45
        Console.WriteLine(".NET 4.5");
#endif
        var obj = new Model(123, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 });
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Example);
        foreach (var val in clone.A)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the speedy reply! Your example works for me as well. Also, I have encountered a similar scenario in my project that *does* work. Let me isolate the broken class and see if it still malfunctions in a test app...

Comment: When I could not reproduce the issue, I started looking at things happen around the serialization. Turns out protobuf-net's deserialization works fine, and then [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) goes and ignores the private field in its model binding. This also explains why the response had no problems, as this only applies to the incoming request. @MarcGravell thank you for your help!

Comment: I have now solved my problem being simply using a public `IEnumerable<T>`. I had not realized that protobuf-net supported this yet! This was in part because I initially only tried `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, its countable and guaranteed-to-be-materialized sibling. How do you feel about supporting this useful little interface just like `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @Timo there *is* some code to support the read-only collection types, not sure if it works in that exact case, though; kinda awkward, frankly - lists are a *ton* easier :)

Comment: Interesting, I could only get it to work for `IEnumerable<T>`. I haven't looked at that code, though.